# How to count an array with DOMNode in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have a problem counting the following array $nodes that contains DOMnode from an html page:

```
@$dom_object = new DOMDocument();    
@$dom_object->loadHTML($content);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom_object);
$nodes = $xPath->query('//div[@class="giaeffettuate"]');

count($nodes); // returns 1
count((array) $nodes); // returns 0
```

Why is that?

Comment: Please refer to the PHP Manual for the Return Value of `DOMXPath::query`. It does *not* return an array, but a `DOMNodeList`. Refer to the documentation for that class to learn how to count elements in it.

Comment: Always read the documentation before asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`length`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php#domnodelist.props.length) attribute:

```php
echo $nodes->length;
```